# How to update Nth Element of an array

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Is it possible to update/replace the nth element of an array

input =[1,2,3,4]

Update 3rd element from 3 to 5

Output=[1,2,5,4]]

Comment: Data factory does not support, self referencing variables. you have to do the above with 2 variables. one for temp and other is real.

Comment: Did you tried any expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ADF, self-referencing variables is not supported. So, use a temporary variable first and then reassign that temporary variable value to required one.

If you only want to do it in ADF and not in dataflow, follow the below approach.

I have created two array variables named `x` with values `[1,2,3,4]` and `temp`.

I have created two parameters for **nth element** and **updated value**.

[image]

**X value at start:**

[image]

I have used the below expression to get the updated array.

```
@createArray(take(variables('x'),sub(pipeline().parameters.nth,1)),pipeline().parameters.value,skip(variables('x'),pipeline().parameters.nth))
```

[image]

This will give output like below.

[image]

To get the array in required format, use the below expression and assign the value to required variable.

```
@json(concat('[',replace(replace(string(variables('temp')), '[', ''),']',''),']'))
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @createArray(take(pipeline().parameters.InputArray,pipeline().parameters.Nth),pipeline().parameters.Value,skip(pipeline().parameters.InputArray,add(pipeline().parameters.Nth,1)))

this would be the correct expression as Array elemnt begins with zero ideally

Comment: @Nandan, yeah I agree with you. If we want to update nth index value, your expression is better. If for nth element, then mine is Ok I guess : ).

Comment: Yup,thanks for clarifications. I created it based on index!!

Answer (score 1):

Similar thread:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1183224/how-to-update-nth-element-of-an-array

```
{
"name": "UpdateArray",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Set variable1",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "Inter",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@take(pipeline().parameters.IA,int(pipeline().parameters.ElementNbr))",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach1",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Set variable1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@variables('Inter')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Append variable1",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "Final",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@item()",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Append variable2",
            "type": "AppendVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "ForEach1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "Final",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.IS",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Set variable2",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Append variable2",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "Inter",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@skip(pipeline().parameters.IA,add(int(pipeline().parameters.ElementNbr),1))",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach2",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Set variable2",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@variables('Inter')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Append variable1_copy1",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "Final",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@item()",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "IA": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5,
                9
            ]
        },
        "IS": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "6"
        },
        "ElementNbr": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "3"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "Inter": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "Final": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
```

}

But the proposal by @rakesh would be better :) rather than having multiple iterations

Comment: Thank you but i would like to avoid iteration activity