# How to swap the elements of an array

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Is there any way to swap the elemnts of an array

input = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

swap 2nd index and 3rd index values

Output= [1,2,4,3,5,6]

Comment: can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: I think the idea is similar to the question [you asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75533993/how-to-update-nth-element-of-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

In ADF, for swapping array there is not a dedicated function is not supported. So, use a temporary variable and then manipulate that temporary variable value to get desire result.

To swap array in ADF follow the below approach.

I have created array variables named  `x`  with values  `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` ,`temp_middle`,`temp_left`,`temp_right`,`temp_combined`,`swapped_array` and two pipeline parameters for indexes to be swapped named `a` and `b`.

[image][image]

Then I split the `x` array using indexes in 3 set variables as left side of minimum index, right side of maximum index and middle part between both index.

- To get Left part in variable `temp_left` I used below expression.

```
@take(variables('x'), pipeline().parameters.a)
```

[image]

- To get Right part in variable `temp_right` I used below expression.

```
@skip(variables('x'), add(pipeline().parameters.b,1))
```

[image]

- To get middle part in variable `temp_middle` I used below expression.

```
@take(skip(variables('x'),add(pipeline().parameters.a,1)),sub(pipeline().parameters.b,add(pipeline().parameters.a,1)))
```

[image]

- After this I took If activity to check if middle part of array is empty or not with expression `@empty(variables('temp_middle'))`

[image]

- If it is empty control will go to true condition and under true condition, we took another set variables to combine all the left, right, middle part and swap the elements. In true condition as middle part is empty, we are omitting it.

```
@createArray(variables('temp_left'),variables('x')[pipeline().parameters.b],variables('x')[pipeline().parameters.a],variables('temp_right'))
```

[image]

This will give output like below.

[image]

- If it is not an empty control will go to false condition and under false condition, we took another set variables to combine all the left, right, middle part and swap the elements. In false condition as middle part is not an empty, we are including it.

```
@createArray(variables('temp_left'),variables('x')[pipeline().parameters.b],variables('temp_middle'),variables('x')[pipeline().parameters.a],variables('temp_right'))
```

[image]

- To get the array in required format, use the below expression and assign the value to required variable (same for both True and false condition).

```
@json(concat('[',replace(replace(string(variables('temp')), '[', ''),']',''),']'))
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]